# Posting of questions and answers

Tags: discussion

There are probably numerous problems/questions which at one time or another we've encountered and wished the answer existed on StackExchange (or similar) but ended up having to figure out/resolve ourselves.

With a view to building up content, especially so it can be indexed by the likes of google etc, can we perhaps come up with a list of these more complex questions, and then providing the answers (possibly getting further feedback too)? Possibly also trying to build up a list of those questions which we've often seen posted on the like of the developer.force.com forums which have standard patterns/solutions.

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for stackoverflows thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 7):

By all means, do this - but make sure you're documenting solutions to *actual problems that you've faced (or observed)*, not just making up hypothetical questions; the latter tends to produce poor results.

I wouldn't get too meta about it though; rather than trying to build a list of such things, just post them - if you have a question and *don't* have an answer to it, just ask it. Again, avoid *making up* questions - rarely does this produce good results, since you then lack a strong motivation to see it answered well.

Comment: I've thought of doing this very thing...when I have the time, of course :-).